# IE error: Your browser is not supported for this application

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using IE 8 and i am geting this error: Your browser is not supported for this application. How to disable this error in IE?

[image]

Comment: …by disabling JavaScript. Maybe update your question, mention that you are using Selenium and even though IE 5.5 and higher is supported, you still get an unsupported error in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the script at www.sunnycars.com/mode/item/script_check.js.

```
var ie5=document.getElementById?document.all?true:false:false;
var ie55=document.getElementById?document.all?(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5")!=-1)?true:false:false:false;
...
oldie = ie4?(ie5?(ie55?false:(ie6?false:(ie7?false:true))):true):false;
```

In other words the joker who wrote this thinks that any browser that supports `document.all` but which doesn't have “MSIE 5.5” to “MSIE 7.0” in the User-Agent string, must be IE5.0 and thus too old. The idea that there might be newer versions of IE than 7, or other browsers that support `document.all`, never seems to have crossed their mind.

UA-sniffing is highly questionable at the best of times but this is a particularly bone-headed specimen. If you are the webmaster for this site, the best thing to do would be to get rid of this script completely, as it doesn't do anything worthwhile and never did. You'll probably also want to look at updating the rest of the scripting, which also exhibits signs of decay.

If you are just a visitor to this site, the only thing you can do to avoid the error is to stop visiting it.

Comment: Heh. No, I just have a very low tolerance for UA-sniffing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable this error. The application you are running probably has a Javascript code to check the browser compatibility. This error is not thrown by your browser.  You might want to upgrade to a later version of the application.(selenium ). But if you just want to disable it, then you can try to disable javascript in your browser. You will get an ugly error icon instead. (I was just trying to answer  your question, its far from an ideal solution.)

(Note: Since I am sure that the application you are using uses activex plugins, it may not run at all in IE8)

Answer (score 0):

Try not going to that website or try not using IE.

Comment: hmm in win7 i am using IE9 and it is ok. But win2003 not support IE9 just IE8 :((

Comment: is this your website are you trying to program it to not show up?